# Copying a multi dimensional array of nodes into another array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am looking to convert a multi dimensional array into another multidimensional array using a recursive function.

Source array :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [source_name] => kk56ca1d0f2378f
            [company_id] => 1
            [lft] => 1
            [rgt] => 18
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [source_name] => kk56ca1d17f3f63
                            [company_id] => 1
                            [lft] => 2
                            [rgt] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [source_name] => kk56ca1d1ebe975
                            [company_id] => 1
                            [lft] => 4
                            [rgt] => 13
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [source_name] => kk56ca1fc882ac0
                                            [company_id] => 1
                                            [lft] => 5
                                            [rgt] => 10
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

which I need to get into the format of

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => kk56ca1d0f2378f
            [parent_id] => 0
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [text] => kk56ca1d17f3f63
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [text] => kk56ca1d1ebe975
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [text] => kk56ca1fc882ac0
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                            [nodes] => Array
                                                (

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 15
                                            [text] => kk
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                            [nodes] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have been trying for hours and getting nowhere with this. Any help would be really appreciated.

The source array has associative indexes (though they are numbers) and the destination array has numerical indexes. Besides this, just need to remove a few indexes and change names of a few.

EDIT :

Specific changes :

- change index name source_name to text
- change index name children to nodes
- unset indexes lft, rgt, company_id

I do not have much experience with recursion so I have trying fruitlessly.

This is what I could come up with :

```
// pass array of nodes
function convert_array($from){

    // this is a node
    if(isset($from['source_name']))
    {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id'] = $from['id'];

        convert_array($from['children']);
    }
    // this is an array of nodes
    else
    {
        foreach($from as $arr)
        {
            $ret = convert_array($arr);
            print_r($ret);
        }

    }
}
```

But I am not able to understand what data to be returned and how the new array builds up from the return values.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to change in the first array? Or do you just want to renumber the indexes in the top level of the array?

Comment: Can you reduce your example, its hard to see, waht you want to achieve, the both arrays have much difference in many aspects...

Comment: Arrays aren't rocket science. As the two comments above me already said: Figure out, what it exactly is you want to do. And then just do it ;) [`foreach()`](https://php.net/foreach) is great for arrays in PHP. And if you have unknown dimensions, look up recursion. Then it should be as much a few simple lines of code

Comment: I have modified my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here the working function:

```
function convert_array( $array )
{
    $retval = array();

    foreach( $array as $row )
    {
        $child              = array();
        $child['id']        = $row['id'];
        $child['text']      = $row['source_name'];
        $child['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
        if( count( $row['children'] ) )
        { $child['nodes'] = convert_array( $row['children'] ); }
        else
        { $child['nodes'] = array(); }
        $retval[] = $child;
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

<kbd>**[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/6LTk1)**</kbd>

I think it is self-explanatory, BTW: we init an empty array (`$retval`), then we perform a `foreach` loop through all array argument: for each element, we init a new array and we add it `id`, `source_name` as `text` and `parent_id`; if the `children` index has elements, we perform a recursive call to fill `nodes` array index, otherwise we set it to empty array.